# Sort week wise date in string format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table with two columns `week` and `amount` as shown below

```
Week                      Amount
--------------------------------
1w - 1m - 2015             1000
4w - 8m - 2015             1000
2w - 2m - 2015             1000
4w - 6m - 2015             1000
3w - 3m - 2015             1000
3w - 10m - 2015            1000
1w - 10m - 2015            1000
3w - 12m - 2015            1000
1w - 6m - 2016             1000
2w - 6m - 2016             1000
3w - 6m - 2016             1000
4w - 6m - 2016             1000
3w - 8m - 2016             1000
2w - 9m - 2016             1000
```

How can I sort this table by week (as date)?

My desired output is:

```
     Week                    Amount
    --------------------------------
    1w - 1m - 2015             1000
    2w - 2m - 2015             1000
    3w - 3m - 2015             1000
    4w - 6m - 2015             1000
    4w - 8m - 2015             1000
    1w - 10m - 2015            1000
    3w - 10m - 2015            1000
    3w - 12m - 2015            1000
    1w - 6m - 2016             1000
    2w - 6m - 2016             1000
    3w - 6m - 2016             1000
    4w - 6m - 2016             1000
    3w - 8m - 2016             1000
    2w - 9m - 2016             1000
```

Comment: Is data present same as the above??

Comment: Tell us the data type of the Week column.

Comment: @Dour High Arch datatype is varchar

Comment: @Shakeer Mirza Yes data is same as above

Comment: Why wouldn't you include the week start date in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select *
 From  YourTable
 Order by right([Week],4)
         ,cast(substring([Week],charIndex('m',[Week])-2,2) as int)
         ,left([Week],1)
```

Returns

```
week            Amount
1w - 1m - 2015  1000
2w - 2m - 2015  1000
3w - 3m - 2015  1000
4w - 6m - 2015  1000
4w - 8m - 2015  1000
1w - 10m - 2015 1000
3w - 10m - 2015 1000
3w - 12m - 2015 1000
1w - 6m - 2016  1000
2w - 6m - 2016  1000
3w - 6m - 2016  1000
4w - 6m - 2016  1000
3w - 8m - 2016  1000
2w - 9m - 2016  1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Bulding up on accepted answer, if table structure can be changes (add some columns), it can be made to store data in much more friendly way, by using persisted computed columns. This costs some storage and some extra computation effort on data insertion, but it will make most future selection faster, since string parsing is no longer required. Also, each column has the appropriate type, so it is harder to get invalid data.

**Setup:**

```
create table WeekData
(
    WeekStr VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Amount INT,
    YearVal AS CAST (Right(WeekStr,4) AS SMALLINT) PERSISTED,
    MonthVal AS cast(substring(WeekStr,charIndex('m', WeekStr)-2,2) as SMALLINT),
    WeekVal AS CAST(left(WeekStr,1) AS TINYINT)
)

insert into WeekData (WeekStr, Amount) 
VALUES ('1w - 1m - 2015', 1000),
('4w - 8m - 2015', 1000),
('2w - 2m - 2015', 1000),
('4w - 6m - 2015', 1000),
('3w - 3m - 2015', 1000),
('3w - 10m - 2015', 1000),
('1w - 10m - 2015', 1000),
('3w - 12m - 2015', 1000),
('1w - 6m - 2016', 1000),
('2w - 6m - 2016', 1000),
('3w - 6m - 2016', 1000),
('4w - 6m - 2016', 1000),
('3w - 8m - 2016', 1000),
('2w - 9m - 2016', 1000)
GO
```

**Select**

```
select WeekStr, Amount 
from WeekData
order by YearVal, MonthVal, WeekVal
```